# Why I can't build my 'feed_widget' code with flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, build, flutter-layout

That is feed_widget code.
First of all, I use flutter and firebase.
Firebase database contain with 'displayName', 'contents', 'likedUsers'.
I modify code because issue of truncated text.
But I can't build with new code.

[The Old Code](Modified area)

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          width: 16.0,
        ),
        Text(
          '좋아요 ${widget.document['likedUsers']?.length ?? 0}개',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 8.0,
    ),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          width: 16.0,
        ),
        Text(
          widget.document['displayName'],
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 8.0,
        ),
        Text(widget.document['contents']),
      ],
    ),
```

[The NEW Code](Modified area)

```
Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text(
              '좋아요 ${widget.document['likedUsers']?.length ?? 0}개',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: const [
                Text(
                  widget.document['displayName'],
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 8.0,
                ),
                Expanded(child: Text(widget.document['contents']),),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: lib/feed_widget.dart:83:26: Error: Undefined name 'widget'.
                  '좋아요 ${widget.document['likedUsers']?.length ?? 0}개',
lib/feed_widget.dart:91:23: Error: Undefined name 'widget'.
                      widget.document['displayName'],
lib/feed_widget.dart:97:42: Error: Undefined name 'widget'.
                    Expanded(child: Text(widget.document['contents']),),

Comment: * Where:
Script '/Users/leejaeyoon/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/leejaeyoon/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: check out my answer blew.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass variable as text of `Text` Widget you can't use `const`, so remove those `const` in your new code:

```
Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                   Text(
                    '좋아요 ${widget.document['likedUsers']?.length ?? 0}개',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children:  [
                      Text(
                        widget.document['displayName'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8.0,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(widget.document['contents']),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```